# Run script when someone inserts or updates a row in certain Table

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I am using **MYSQL** under **ubuntu**. I want to **run a certain program automatically when inserting or updating row in a certain table**. The program is actually sending request to a php on the same server. The php script is implemented and it notifies all clients that "data is updated, please get it". How can I do it?

Thank You

Comment: what do you mean by program? do you have a code specific problem ? your question seems vague to me i"m not sure ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have control of the script, the easiest way would be to create your own `query()` method that wraps around whatever SQL query call you need to make. You can put something in there to see if there's an UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT and if so fire off your "data updated" notice.

Answer (score 4):

best solution is create cron job and use system command in cron file.

Comment: Do you mean a cron job that check whether the database has new or updated data? Would it be too resources-consuming as it keep running.

Comment: Yes, it will take resource lot

Answer (score 2):

That probably cannot be done without major security issues on MySQL server.

You could to this from PHP. either execute the program when you send the query to MySQL or create a CronJob.